# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null - product\list\toolbar.phtml on line 18

Tags: toolbar, magento-2.1.2

In Magento 2 I just want to move toolbar before breadcrumbs so to do so I've placed following code in my custom theme **catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
```

But in frontend I'm getting error.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in \frontend\Vender\Theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list\toolbar.phtml on line 18
```

What is this error?? How can I solve it??